# Php and MySQL: retrieving data from a database based on the link a user clicks

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, dreamweaver

I've put a set of small images to function as links (around 50 more or less) on a page. In that same page I have a content place holder to display data from the database, and I have a table saved in phpmyadmin that has a set of fields filled with data.

What I want is when the user clicks on a certain image link, the data related to that image gets retrieved into the site. So I want the data to be retrieved to match the image clicked.

I know how to retrieve data from a database using the binding pannel in dreamweaver, and I know this has to do with filtering the data retrieved but I don't know how to do it.. How can I make this process work?

If it helps I'm also using Jquery CSS and javascript in this project.

**The project looks like this:**

http://i725.photobucket.com/albums/ww256/flower1991a/world_zps26b7083d.png

**HTML code:**

it doesnt show I took a screenshot of it:

http://i725.photobucket.com/albums/ww256/flower1991a/a_zpsa138aa52.png

**jQuery code:**

$(document).ready(function() {
// begin Ready

```
//...................................................
// When the form changes
$('#mapForm').change(function() {

    var selectedContinent = $('#mapForm option:selected').val();
    if (selectedContinent == 'ALL'){
        $('a.dot').slideDown(1000);
    }else{
        $('a.dot[continent = "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideDown(1000);
        $('a.dot[continent != "'+selectedContinent+'"]').slideUp(1000);
    }

});

//...................................................
// When a dot is clicked
$('a.dot').click(function(){

    $('a.dot').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    var city = '.city_detail#' + $(this).attr('city');
    var htmlCode = $(city).html();

    $('.detail_container').fadeOut(500, function(){
        $('.detail_container .city_detail').html(htmlCode);
        $('.detail_container').fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

// end Ready
});

Comment: what have you done so far?? show the code please

Comment: @AjeetManral its a project I downloaded of the internet. It works in a way that when the user clicks on the image link (dot) the data appears in the text field in that same page, the text appears (which is originally saved on the html page and hidden using CSS) based on the dot the user clicks, that part is done with jQuery. However what I've done was I saved the data into a MySQL database (for around 50 dot images) to make the data easier to handle and edit, and now instead of showing the data when a dot is clicked from the html code I want to show data when a dot is clicked directly from DB

Comment: @AjeetManral I've put the code in the Question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a PHP script which takes a REQUEST variable parameter depending on the image that has been clicked, and which returns the data for that image.

You can then make a call to that PHP script via AJAX and populate whichever area of the page you want to with the data retrieved.